# Extreme values of a function with a condition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry

Could you tell me how to find extreme values of this function?

$f_p(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (\frac{x_1^p + x_2^p + x_3^p}{3})^{\frac{1}{p}}$, $p>0$

Here $x_1. x_2, x_3$ are lengths of the sides of a triangle inscribed in a unit circle.

Firstly, I don't know how to formulate the condition for $x_i$s.

And secondly, could you explain to me how to find extreme values of function with three variables?

Thank you.

Comment: You are sure that statement is proper? Isn't it $\left(\frac{x_1^{1/p}+x_2^{1/p}+x_3^{1/p}}{3}\right)^{p}$?

Comment: I'm very sorry. There should be $\frac{1}{p}$

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $p$ is fixed?

Comment: Yes, $p$ is fixed.

Comment: then look here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean maximum is achieved iff it is equilateral triangle

Comment: Could you help me prove that?

Comment: I've tried Lagrange multipliers. But after over an hour I realized it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I would first try to find the relation between x1, x2 and x3 using the fact that those are sides of a triangle inscribed in unit circle. Then see if you can write x1 in terms of x2 and x3. Once that is done you can reduce the original function's dependency to x2 and x3 by substituting x1. Then you can use multivariate calculus to find the extremas.

Here is a good document that explains  http://cramton.umd.edu/econ300/09-extreme-values-multivariate.pdf

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a hint as to how to find the relation between $x_i$s?

Comment: You can use the formula $R=\frac{x_1 x_2 x_3}{4S}$ where $S$ is the area and $R$ is the radius.
For $S$ use Heron's formula .

Comment: Could you tell me if there's a more effective way of solving this problem other than solving a system of four polynomial equations with four variables?

Comment: You should be able to reduce it to two variables only. Notice S is the are of a unit circle with R = 1. Since P is fixed you will be solving for x2 and x3 in terms of p. That is off course after applying multivariate operations. Partial with respect to each variable. I am not sure if there is any other option other than multivariate calculus.

Comment: Well, using user68061's clue I get $2\sqrt{(x_1+x_2+x_3)(-x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_1-x_2+x_3)(x_1+x_2-x_3)}=x_1x_2x_3$. This is my constraint and the function is $f_p(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (\frac{x_1^p + x_2^p + x_3^p}{3})^{\frac{1}{p}}$, when $p>0$ is fixed. Using Lagrange multiplier I write 4 equations with four unknowns $\lambda, x_1, x_2, x_3$. Could you explain to me a bit more how to reduce the number of variables to two?